# MYSQL /SQL multiple alias base on column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: states (id, name); hospitals (id, name, level_id, state_id); level (id, name). The table (level) shows the quality of each hospital. A States can have several hospitals that have different quality of service (level). I want to achieve a MySQL query like below

Tables :

level

```
id| name    |  
1 | level 1 |  
2 | level 2 | 
3 | level 3 |
```

hospitals

```
id| name | level_id | state_id  
1 | Hos A| 1        | 22  
2 | Hos B| 3        | 7   
3 | Hos C| 2        | 13  
...
```

result:

```
states | level 1 | level 2| level 3 | total
state 1| 0       | 1      | 1       | 2
state 2| 3       | 4      | 7       | 14  
...
```

I have tried something along this line but just got stuck. Any help will be appreciated

```
SELECT state.name states, hos.level_id 'level 1', hos.level_id 'level 2', hos.level_id 'level 3'
FROM state

LEFT JOIN hospital hos ON hos.state_id = state.id

ORDER BY state.name
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select state,
       sum(level_id = 1) as num_1,
       sum(level_id = 2) as num_2,
       sum(level_id = 3) as num_3,
       count(*) as total
from hospitals h
group by state;
```

Comment: Isn't there suppose to be a join somewhere?

Comment: @Lekia . . . A `JOIN` doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon Linoff I just made a little tweak to it and got it working.